# exec-maven-plugin doesn't use third-party repos

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have a couple of third-party repos configured.  I know they're configured correctly because it's downloading artifacts from them.  But `exec-maven-plugin` doesn't seem to recognize those third-party repos.  It looks for its dependency in Maven Central and then tells me the POM doesn't exist there.  Of course it doesn't; it's in the third party repo!  Do I need to do something special to tell `exec-maven-plugin` to use the third-party repo?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>emulation</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>krum.jplex.JPlex</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>${basedir}/src/main/jplex/EmulationLexer.jplex</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jplex</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/jplex</argument>
                </arguments>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jplex</sourceRoot>
                <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.chalcodes.jplex</groupId>
            <artifactId>JPlex</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: exec-maven-plugin only deal with program execution, it doesn't manage the dependencies for you. Did you run it on the same exact environment? (Same PC, jdk version etc)

Comment: The POM that contains this plugin tag successfully downloads other dependencies from the same third-party repo where exec-maven-plugin should be finding its dependency.

Comment: Are you saying that the dependency tag here has no effect, and I should put it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

A reading of [Using Plugin Dependencies instead of Project Dependencies](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html), indicates you will need to specify the following (in addition to what you have)

```
<configuration>
      <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
      <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
      <executableDependency>
        <groupId>com.chalcodes.jplex</groupId>
        <artifactId>1.2.1</artifactId>
      </executableDependency>
...
</configuration
```